# Should my directory structure in Windows look like this?

Tags: windows-xp, home-directory

I believe I have weird placement of my files on my Windows computer. I'm not sure what the correct way it is supposed to be. For example, all the programs that I use are located in `C:\Documents and Settings\David Godfrey\Start Menu\Programs`. Is it really supposed to be in `Documents and Settings`?

I would expect the directory to be something like `C:\Users\David Godfrey\Start Menu\Programs`. Why does it use `Documents and Settings` and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's really supposed to be so. Windows 2000 and Windows XP always put user profiles under `\Documents and Settings`; this was changed to `\Users` only starting with Windows Vista. (Although it's possible to relocate them in XP through Registry.)

Comment: Addendum:  Windows 7 fakes **Documents and Settings** with a junction to c:\users

Comment: What a relief! I thought I messed up my computer somehow!

Comment: Editing the registry directly to relocate those folders is not really supported at all. See [The long and sad story of the Shell Folders key](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx). Also, official source of what cybernard commented about: [Junction Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @and31415: I am not talking about Shell Folders. I am talking about moving the _entire profile_ through `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

Comment: @grawity I see. Care to point it out explicitly?

Comment: grawity is right; you can easily change the name of the userdir with e.g. nLite - I commonly use "home" as a tribute to *n*x, but using "users" or "profiles" is still much better than those awkward "Documents and Settings"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, should be so. See some changes that took place in the folder structure between xp and windows 7.

```
The list below describes some of the the commonly used folders and
their new locations.

XP: Documents and Settings
Windows 7: Users

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\My Documents
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\Documents

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\My Documents\My Music
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\Music

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\My Documents\My Pictures
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\Pictures

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\My Documents\My Videos
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\Videos

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\Application Data
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\AppData\Roaming

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\Local Settings
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\Local

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\Start Menu
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

XP: Documents and Settings\$USER$\Templates
Windows 7: Users\$USER$\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates

XP: Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu 
Windows 7: ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

XP: Documents and Settings\Default User
Windows 7: Users\Default
```

<sub>[**`Source`**](http://w3.unisa.edu.au/ists/Staff/Purchasing/Software/OperatingSystems/Windows7/differences.asp)</sub>